# Resolver Scripts Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

[image: debo usar esta base de datos]

**Tengo que resolver estas preguntas**

Cree la función FU_PROMEDIO_SALARY que reciba un parámetro para el DEPARTMENT_ID y otro para el mes de contrato (HIRE_DATE). La función debe devolver el mínimo sueldo (SALARY) de los empleados que coincidan con el departamento y mes de contrato. Realice una consulta a la tabla EMPLOYEES donde se muestre el resultado de la función.

```
create or replace function FU_PROMEDIO_SALARY (Depid in employees.department_id%type, mes NUMBER) return NUMBER
is
salariominimo employees.salary%type; 
begin
select employees.salary into salariominimo from employees where salary=(select min(salary) from jobs) and 
extract(month from HIRE_DATE)=mes and employees.department_id= Depid; 
return salariominimo;
end FU_PROMEDIO_SALARY;


set SERVEROUTPUT on 
declare
resultado employees.salary%type;
begin
resultado:= FU_PROMEDIO_SALARY(100,03);
dbms_output.put_line('SALARIO MINIMO: '||resultado);
end;
```

Cree el procedimiento SP_REP_EMPLEADO que reciba como parámetro el JOB_ID e imprima en pantalla los empleados que pertenecen a dicho trabajo (JOB_ID). El reporte debe mostrar el nombre completo, salario y comisión (commission_pct * salary), en caso la comisión sea nula mostrar 0. Haga uso de un cursor para recorrer la lista de empleados. Valide el procedimiento mostrando el resultado de su ejecución.

```
create or replace procedure SP_REP_EMPLEADO (jobID in varchar2)
as
codigo employees.employeeid%type; 
comision NUMBER;
begin
  declare cursor curEmpleado is select employeeid, salary*commission_pct
          into codigo , comision
          from employees WHERE job_id= jobID;
  begin for fila in curEmpleado
  loop
  dbms_output.put_line('NADA');
 end loop;
    end ;
    end SP_REP_EMPLEADO;



select first_name, salary*commission_pct  from employees;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.